# Markers do not appear on Google Map on www.website.com vs. website.com

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a website that includes a google map, users can add markers to the maps.

If I go to the site this way:

www.site.com

I see the markers on the map.

If I go to the site this way:

site.com

The markers do not appear on the map.

Any idea why and how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps if you shared some of the code you were using people might be better able to diagnose your problem

Comment: how do you define the marker-images? Where are the maps, may we take a look at the site?

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to use 301 redirects to not have two different ways to access the site.  I always set all access from site.com to www.site.com.  It might make a difference with some API's and it does confuse some people.  It is better for search engines as well.

The easiest way, especially in regards to SEO friendlies in Apache is to set the .httaccess to allow for 301 redirects.

It is best practice and should also fix little issues like this that you are experiencing.

```
create an .htaccess file in your main folder
```

then add the following code and then save

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also, some server hosts have this option when adding the domain to your control panel.  It will ask to redirect all trafic from non www to www.

Comment: How would that solve or explain the issue. When he says he can access the map on both hosts, the server-configuration seams already be done, otherwise one of the maps wouldn't be accessible at all. The issue must be something else.

Comment: You are missing the point.  He shouldn't have two sites and accesses for one.  It is bad for search engines and in the google config or whereever is seeing www. it doesn't see the other site.  It should be setup to always redirect.  That way if you go to sites.com it would always fail over to www.sites.com and then therefore in his case, always work.  Eliminate the possibility to fail.

Comment: the point is that this question is about missing markers, not about a proper server-configuration

Comment: No other information was provided.  You can set it so that no one ever goes to the site.com again, which is my point, would fix the problem.  If they want to come back and offer more code or what they did then fixing the code is a different story.  But, the solution should indeed work to not have it happen again and if the person's site isn't on Windows it should fix in a matter of a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

"www.example.com" and "example.com" are actually two different addresses. "www" is a subdomain or CNAME just like any other (blog.site.com, app.site.com etc.) There's probably an absolute url somewhere in the code  that relies on the user viewing the site from "www.example.com"

One option: You could set up a re-direct so that all naked domain traffic (example.com) is redirected to www.example.com

See the previous answer from @donlaur (that just popped as I was writing this) for the re-directing using an .htaccess file

Comment: Thanks dude.  Rep point.  This really is the best solution, to get rid of that option of non www altogether.